# How to set (dot) . separated variable in scope using jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to set a value in jsp. I know that can be easily set by

```
     <c:set var="myVar" value="100" scope="session"/>
```

But problem is that my variable name is separated by dot(.) like **sports.football.kick**
I tried by setting in this way

```
     <c:set var="sports.football.kick" value="100" scope="session"/>
```

But it is not setting. How I can set this type of variable in scope using jsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work just fine. Apparently you're accessing it the wrong way. It should be accessed using the brace notation on the session map.

```
${sessionScope['sports.football.kick']}
```

Comment: I tried with <c:set var="${sessionScope['sports.football.kick']}" value="100" />. Throwing exception "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute var does not accept any expressions"

Comment: You don't need to change your `<c:set>`, it's all fine. I have just shown how to access/display it.

Comment: Accessing is not problem. But problem is when I want to set value.

Comment: The way how you set the value is fine. At least, it works fine for me on Tomcat 7 with JSP 2.2/JSTL 1.2.